# Keyboard shortcut for switching tabs in a pane

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

When I have focus on my Debug panel:

[image]

I would like to use the keyboard to switch to the "Console" tab, visible right next to the currently selected "Debugger" tab.

There are several Keymap settings that refer to switching **Editor** tabs, but this is not a code editor window, it is an IntelliJ specific pane. How can I specify a keyboard shortcut for navigating tabs in an IntelliJ pane?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right-clicking the tabs gives the menu:
[image]

(on Mac):

Next tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>right</kbd>

Prev tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>left</kbd>

---

Note that on Mac these keystrokes are automatically configured to switch Spaces. [You need to go into `Keyboard` settings to turn it off](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-for-switching-Spaces-in-Mac-OS-X-Lion)

Answer (score 5):

`alt+right` to move right a tab.

`alt+left` to move left a tab.

You will need to have the correct panel of tabs in the current context for effect. To get to these you can use the shortcuts which are the form `alt+NUM`.

`alt+5` for instance would jump you to the debug panel.